# Rubymotion - undefined method `fontWithName' for UIFont:Class

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I have the following method in a controller which adds a view label as the navigation title

```
def viewSetupTitle

    @titleLabel = UILabel.alloc.initWithFrame([[0, 0], [300, 40]])
    @titleLabel.text = "My App"
    @titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor
    @titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor

    @titleLabelFont = UIFont.fontWithName("Avenir-Black")
    @titleLabel.font = @titleLabelFont

    @titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    self.navigationItem.titleView = @titleLabel

end
```

When I run `rake` I get the following error:

```
2014-05-29 10:54:00.519 My App[14839:70b] query_controller.rb:19:in `viewSetupTitle': undefined method `fontWithName' for UIFont:Class (NoMethodError)
    from query_controller.rb:8:in `viewDidLoad'
    from app_delegate.rb:9:in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:'
2014-05-29 10:54:00.520 My App[14839:70b] query_controller.rb:19:in `viewSetupTitle': undefined method `fontWithName' for UIFont:Class (NoMethodError)
    from query_controller.rb:8:in `viewDidLoad'
    from app_delegate.rb:9:in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:'
2014-05-29 10:54:00.523 My App[14839:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NoMethodError', reason: 'query_controller.rb:19:in `viewSetupTitle': undefined method `fontWithName' for UIFont:Class (NoMethodError)
    from query_controller.rb:8:in `viewDidLoad'
    from app_delegate.rb:9:in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:'
```

If I call `fontWithName`, `fontName` or any other method on the UIFont class I get a similar error.

I'm confused because if I run `puts UIFont.instance_methods.inspect` in my code I can see all of the above methods (and the others that should be there according to Apple's documentation).

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You simply didn't add the second part of the method (RubyMotion iOS/OS X methods include what looks like keyword arguments or a hash of options). The full method name is `UIFont#fontWithName:size:`.

You needed to add a size. `UIFont.fontWithName("Avenir-Black", size: 14)`, as it's not an optional argument, but actually part of the method's name.